# Can't generate Diagram Editor in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, emf, eclipse-gmf

This is an image of *Eclipse GMF: a graphical editor for EMF models*:

[image: Eclipse GMF: a graphical editor for EMF models]

When I click 'Generate Diagram Editor' the problem occurs:

> An internal error occurred during: "Execute Templates".
>   org.eclipse.m2m.internal.qvt.oml.compiler.QVTOCompiler.compile

What can I do to fix this?